# How can I run php commands directly in console?

Tags: php, command, command-line-interface

When I run PHP in my **console** (any cli application) and I sending a command like below, it not returned anything!

```
echo 'Hi!';
```

Is there any way to run PHP commands **directly** in console or just we can run a `.php` file?

**Note:** My environment variables and path is OK.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Comment: if you need a REPL shell you should look at [psysh](https://psysh.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use PHP's interactive shell

```
php -a
echo 'Hi!';
```